# Parse: send push notifications from app

Tags: android, parsing, push-notification, parse-platform

I am wondering how to send a parse push notification directly from my android app to evryone else using my app. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can do this using GCM push notification. [http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/]

Comment: use this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to use `Parse`, Go to parse **dashboard** and there you will see the settings for push where you will find this client-side push setting.

```
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
String message = "Client message" + Integer.toString(i++);
push.setChannel("Channel Name");
push.setMessage(message);
push.sendInBackground();
```

Comment: can you schedule from within the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can send push notification from client side as metioned by @Dmitry

However parse **strongly recommend not to** use that feature [Security vulnerabilites issues]

Parse developers recommend "**Cloud code**" to send push notification to other users from your app.

Please read this
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/

Comment: the link is broken